# Spring SAML multi-tenancy and entity alias

Tags: single-sign-on, multi-tenant, spring-saml

If possible if I want to deploy only one web app which is my Service Provider but can do the SSO by multiple domain (multiple SP but the same IDP)? I mean that my Service Provider will have 2 SP metadata and each of them have a different domain. Here is my sample:

http://server-domain1-abc:port/saml/SSO/alias/sp1

http://server-domain2-xyz:port/saml/SSO/alias/sp2

I read from http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#configuration-entity-alias and see that Spring SAML using alias to differentiate Service Provider instance. I'm not sure if we can configure different domains for different SP instance.

Comment: I am not sure understanding your problem. Your 2 SP are on the same Web APP?

Comment: Yes, 2 SP are on the same web app.

Comment: Finally I can achieve this by overriding some class of Spring SAML library.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: Could you please explain WHICH class of Spring SAML you have overriden?

Comment: Can you please explain how you achieve this ?